# Upgrading OpenSSL in Android

Tags: android, c++, openssl

I've spent the last 2 days trying to upgrade OpenSSL in a native android app. Everything I've tried doesn't seem to make a difference.
Whenever I run `unzip -p YourApk.apk | strings | grep "OpenSSL"` as requested by Google to verify the version of OpenSSL in use, I keep getting the same old version "1.0.1h".

I've tried updating SmartFox, Boost, cURL, and OpenSSL to 1.0.2g but the result remains the same.

Please someone, how can I determine where this old version of OpenSSL is coming from and which library in the app is using it?

Comment: Remove the old version of OpenSSL from your build system and see what fails to build.

Comment: If I knew at the time where the OpenSSL library even was, I would have tried that :)

Answer (score 1):

A little more digging got me onto this:
https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x-3rd-party-libs-bin

Our app (running on Cocos2d-x) was using a prebuilt libcurl library that was using the old version of OpenSSL. Using the updated libcurl from the site fixed the issue.